# Jquery for updating label value with the value entered in textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my jquery for displaying a textbox on clicking  anchor tag

```
$("a").click(function () {

var textbox = $('<input id="txt1" type="text" />')

var oldText = $(this).text();

 $(this).replaceWith(textbox);

           textbox.val(oldText);

     $(this).html($('<input id="txt1" type="text" />').val())

     });
```

My anchor tag

```
 <a>hello</a>
```

Using this when textbox is displayed with text i want to change the text in the textbox and display back  the new text of anchortag

Comment: Do you have txt1 on the form (page)?

Comment: $('<input id="txt1" type="text" />').val() is an empty string since $('<input id="txt1" type="text" />') is a new element with no value attribute. If you want to select your txt1 element you need to use $('#txt1')

Comment: Why do you want to update the anchor-tag after replacing it? After replacing it it does not exist anymore...

Comment: Are you trying to get this? `<a><input id="txt1" type="text" value="hello" /></a>`

Comment: No,Intially i will have a anchor tag with some text,Once i click this i would be getting a textbox with anchor tag text @flec

Comment: @SravanL Could you show me what the output html should look line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('html').click(function(e){
        if(e.target.id == 'txt1' || e.target.id == 'link1') {
                var textbox = $('<input id="txt1" type="text" />')
                var oldText = $(jQuery("#link1")).text();
                $(jQuery("#link1")).replaceWith(textbox);
                textbox.val(oldText);
                $(jQuery("#link1")).html($('<input id="txt1" type="text" />').val())
       } else {
          var newText =  jQuery('#txt1').val()
          var link = jQuery("<a id='link1'></a>");
          jQuery('#txt1').replaceWith(link);
          jQuery('#link1').text(newText);
      }
    });
});
</script>
<html>
<body>
<a id="link1">hello</a></body>
</html>
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4YYrP/)

Comment: But the problem is  if i have n number of anchor tags i am writing sam e jquery for each and every tag .So i am trying using single jquery for multiple anchor tags  which is not  working properly ,if i update one textbox and move to next one ,the previous anchor tag is disappearing      @Nishu tayal

Comment: @SravanL Have you tried my solution? It is shorter and should work anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to get but the following code makes the dynamic anchor text editing. I think there is no need to replace `<a>` element, we can just hide it:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("<input />").val($(this).hide().text()).on("blur", function() {
        $(this).prev("a").text(this.value).show();
        $(this).remove();
    }).insertAfter(this).trigger("focus");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8dpyG/

Comment: I tried it and thanks for your help but This is not working in my mvc3 application @VisioN

Comment: @SravanL That is very strange. The code is quite straightforward. It should work fine. However, I'm not an expert in M$ stuff so possibly there are some limits.